# disable click event on parent jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a site developed in PHp and jQuery.
I have an image over another image in position absolute.
Small image has event click and its parent have another event click. But when I click on the small image I don't want that the event of the parent is fired
Example:
[image]

If I click on the "ok" image the parent fire event click and i have two action, one from the "ok" image and another from the parent.

I have tried in this mode:

```
$(document).on('click','.social-like',function(event){
   //click on "ok" image
   event.preventDefault();
});
$(document).on('click','.block-shirt',function(){
  //click on rectangle
});
```

CSS:

```
.block-shirt{
    float:left;
    width:133px;
    height:170px;
}
.tee{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:15px;
    margin-top:5px;
    width:103px;
    z-index:5;
}
.social-like{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    right:20px;
    z-index:10;
    width:24px;
    height:32px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="block-shirt">
   <img src="rectangle.png" class="tee"/>
   <div class="social-like"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to filter target:

```
$(document).on('click','.block-shirt',function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('.social-like')) return;
    //else do some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$('.block-shirt').click(function(e){
  if ($(e.target).is('.social-like'))
        return false; // do what you want
  else
        //.block-shirt clicked code
```

from : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/click-events-on-absolute-positioned-elements

http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop propagation of the event from child to parent

Try

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

for the child

Comment: doesn't works if using delegation because event is fired at delegate level

Answer (score 1):

For this aim use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Use event.preventDefault() if you don't want default action f.e. redirect on click on  tag

Answer (score 1):

Bind the event to the child directly not to the document

```
$('.social-like').on("click",function(e){e.stopPropagation()})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ikeful/1/edit) i just created.

in short i have used `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the bubbling of click event to its parent element. it will prevent any parent handlers from being executed.

also to prevent/cancel just default action, you should normally use `event.preventDefault()` rather then `return false`.